# Nesting an if statement inside an array loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

Trying to follow an exercise for college and completely lost. As an example app class and instan object challenge, we are tasked to create an app that asks a user for how many subjects they are taking (via scanner) and then using arrays to record each score they have for each subject (so if they took 5 subjects, they enter 5 scores between 1-100). The instantiable should then take those scores, assign a grade as a string to each entry in the array and then get the average score for the user.

e.g. if I enter 4 subjects, I get prompted to enter 4 int values, then I should see the corresponding grade for each subject as a row, and another that calculated the average score of the 4 entered.

Instantiable class object

```
public class GradesAverage{
//Data member declaration (variables, but instantiable class name) - always private
    private int subjects;
    private int[] score;
    String[] grade;
    private int avg;
    private int tally;

//Constructor
    public GradesAverage(){

    }
//Setters - inputs (pulling from App class)
    public void setSubjects(int subjects){
        this.subjects=subjects;
    }
    public void setScore(int[] score){
        this.score=score;
    }
//Compute- process
    public void computeResults(){
        for(int i=0;i<subjects;i++){
            if(score[i]>=90 && score[i]<=100){
                grade[i]="A";
            }
            else if(score[i]>=80 && score[i]<90){
                grade[i]="A-";
            }
            else if(score[i]>=70 && score[i]<80){
                grade[i]="B";
            }
            else if(score[i]>=60 && score[i]<70){
                grade[i]="B-";
            }
            else if(score[i]>=50 && score[i]<60){
                grade[i]="C";
            }
            else if(score[i]>=40 && score[i]<50){
                grade[i]="D";
            }
            else if(score[i]>=0 && score[i]<40){
                grade[i]="F";
            }
            else{
                grade[i]="ERROR";
            }
            tally=score[i-1]+score[i];
        }

        avg=tally/subjects;
    }
//Getters - outputs (sent to App class)
    public int[] getScore(){
        return score;
    }
    public String[] getGrade(){
        return grade;
    }
    public int getAverage(){
        return avg;
    }
}
```

App class object

```
import java.util.*;
public class GradesAverageApp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
//declare variables
        int subjects=0;
        int[] score=new int[10];
        int avg;
        String[] grade;
        int tally;
//declare and create objects
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        GradesAverage g=new GradesAverage();

//inputs (pulling from user input e.g. scanner)
        System.out.println("Please enter how many subject you are taking");
        subjects=keyboard.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<subjects;i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the score (0-100) for subject #"+(i+1));
            score[i]=keyboard.nextInt();
        }
//declare setters
        g.setSubjects(subjects);
        g.setScore(score);
//compute process
        g.computeResults();
//get results
        grade=g.getGrade();
        avg=g.getAverage();
//outputs (back to the user)
        for(int i=0;i<subjects;i++){
            System.out.println("You scored "+score[i]+" in subject #"+(i+1)+", giving you a final grade of "+grade[i]+".");
        }
        System.out.println("Your overall average score was "+avg);
    }
}
```

I'm still very new to Java but I cannot figure out why the app won't finish the compute stage.
Example of the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at GradesAverage.computeResults(GradesAverage.java:41)
        at GradesAverageApp.main(GradesAverageApp.java:30)
```

Comment: Time to use a debugger or sprinkle your code with `println` statements.  See where your calculations go wrong.

Comment: Didn't downvote but https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 0):

Your direct issue is simple: You have a field named `String[] grade;` in your `GradesAverage` class. Like all fields of non-primitive types that aren't initialized, its initial value is therefore `null`.

You never set it. There's a `setScore` which sets the `score` array, but no `setGrades`.

Later in `computeResult`, you evaluate `grade[i]`. Array brackets 'dereference', they follow the pointer. `x[i]` where `x` is `null` thus gives you a `NullPointerException`.

But, you have an underlying problem.

NB: Java has pointers; it's just that the official term is 'reference', just like java has functions but the official term is 'method'. No matter what you care to call it, they point at things, it's like an address in an address book and not a house. `null` refers to a blank page in the address book, most things you can do with a reference are things you do to the house and not the page in the address book - `arr[idx]` is one such thing. Anytime you ask a reference to do something to the thing it refers to, and that reference is `null`, you get a NullPointerException. You can't very well walk over to the house listed in the address book on page 48 if page 48 is blank.

### Debugging

Experienced programmers can generally look at code like this and just see the problem. However, this 'crystal ball debugging' (where you just look at it ever more intently until you go EUREKA!!!) is not reliable and not how real programmers operate.

Instead, they debug. Debugging is very simple, you simply 'evaluate' what your code is supposed to do, line by line, in your head. Then you compare what you think should happen, with what actually happens. Every time what actually happens diverges from what you thought would happen, you found a bug. Solve it, keep going, until the app does exactly what you wanted it to.

You can use debuggers, which make this easy by letting you inspect variables and execute code one line at a time ('stepping through'). However, if 'learning how to use the debugger' is a bit too much of a learning curve issue right now, you can always toss a boatload of `System.out.println("DBG: Variable x is now " + x);` style statements throughout the code as a poor and inefficient, but easy to learn alternative.